# format numbers in java to remove decimals and add decimals

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I am looking at Java code which will perform following two operations:-

If I am sending value 10.00, my method should format it to 1000 and

If I am getting 1000 in response from 3rd party system, I need to convert 1000 to 10.00 in my another method. Simply whatever decimal value (2 digit's after decimal) I'm sending need to remove decimals and whatever Non-decimal Value I'm receiving need to convert to decimals (2 digits after decimals)

I tried to write the code but it's not working expected. Can anyone please guide me? I'm using JDK 7.

Answer (score 0):

You were supposed to provide your own code which doesn't work, so we can help you figure it out and make it work, not posting a problem and let us do all the work.

Input string and convert it to char array with `toCharArray()` method. Rewrite the array without the dot for the first part. For the second part do the same thing except you insert dot on position you want.

BTW your question is not clear enough, how does the algorithm work, what happens if you get number 15, or 1555...does it translate to 0.15 and 15.55?

Comment: You answer it not enough for both the cases. And requested to provide code and not one line answers

Comment: If I send lets say 100.00 it should convert to 10000 or 1000.00 it should be converted to 100000 (decimal portion should be removed) 
If I'm getting 10000 I need to convert it to 100.00 or If I'm getting 100000 it should convert to 1000.00 like this. Because my gateway don't need decimals and client always needs decimals.. HTH

Comment: Why don't you then just multiply by 100 when sending, and divide by 100 when receiving?